# Properties of $S_d$ sheaf

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

A sheaf $F$ on a scheme $X$ is $S_d$ if for every $x\in X$, $F_x$ has a regular sequence of length at least $\min(d, \text{dim } \mathcal{O}_x)$.

I know when $d=\dim X$, this means $F$ is Cohen-Macaulay. But what properties of $F$ can we get if $d$ is small. Say 1 and 2?

One more specific question, on page 183 of Kollár and Mori's book, they justified a exact sequence remained exact after tensoring with $\omega_X$ by saying $\omega_X$ is S_2, can someone tell me why?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For example, do you know Serre's criterion, which says that a reasonable ring is normal if and only if it satisfies $R_1$ and $S_2$? (In fact $S$ in $S_d$ stands for Serre.) In your last paragraph, it is likely that Kollar is dealing with a Cohen-Macaulay variety $X$, in which case $\omega_X$ is Cohen-Macaulay too.

Comment: @Mohan Yes, I am aware of $R_1$ and $S_2$. Regarding the last paragraph, does $\omega_X$ being CM imply it is flat?

Comment: No, if $X$ is CM, so is $\omega_X$. The latter is flat if and only if $X$ is Gorenstein.